# How to inject IConfiguration into program class on hosted worker service?

Tags: c#

I have a worker service created from the default dotnet new template. I tried to inject the IConfiguration interface to Program class, to get the ConnectionString from appsettings.json. How can I make this happen? I tried the code as below, but I'm getting:

> CS0120: An object reference is required for the nonstatic field, method, or property 'Program.Configuration'

````
public class Program
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration Configuration;

        public Program(IConfiguration configuration)
        {
            Configuration = configuration;
        }
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                    services.AddScoped(factory =>
                    {
                        return new QueryFactory
                        {
                            Compiler = new SqlServerCompiler(),
                            Connection = new SqlConnection(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")),
                        };
                    });
                });
    
        
    }
```v
````

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways of accessing appSettings in Program.cs.

1. Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable()  -> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.getenvironmentvariable?view=net-5.0
2. hostContext.Configuration[] ->
   https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.hosting.hostbuildercontext.configuration?view=dotnet-plat-ext-5.0

for your case, I will recommend second one.

```
public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }
        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                    services.AddScoped(factory =>
                    {
                        return new QueryFactory
                        {
                            Compiler = new SqlServerCompiler(),
                            Connection = new SqlConnection(hostContext.Configuration["DefaultConnection"]),
                        };
                    });
                });
    
        
    }
```